# Clarification on Power Series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

My textbook defines power series in the following way:

> Given that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of complex numbers and $c\in\mathbb{C}$, then the *power series* with initial point $c$ and coefficient $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\left(z-c\right)^n$$
>   (It is implied that for $z=c$ and $n=0$ you have $0^0=1$)

The part that is not clear to me is the one in parenthesis. It is known that $0^0\neq 1$, and if we substitute $c$ into the series we end up with a singularity and therefore the sum would not exist. However, if we let $|z-c|<1$ and $a_n=S$, where $S$ is a constant, then the series converges to $\frac{S}{c-z+1}$. In this case, if we substitute $z=c$, the result would match with the initial definition. So my question is, which approach would be correct, and why? Thank you.

Comment: The intent is that the $n=0$ term is the constant $a_0$. For all $z \neq c$, we have $(z-c)^0 = 1$, and if we adopt the convention that $(z-c)^0 = 1$ even when $z=c$, then the formula $a_0(z-c)^0$ reduces to $a_0$, which is what we want. It would be silly and counterproductive to treat $0^0$ as a special undefined case in this context. If we did that, we would end up having to write something like $$a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(z-c)^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not "known" that $0^0\neq 1$.  The meaning of $0^0$ is a matter of *definition*, and we are free to choose whatever definition we want (as long as we are prepared to deal with the consequences).  In some contexts it makes sense to consider $0^0$ to be undefined, but in many other contexts, it is sensible and useful to define $0^0=1$.  That is what is being done here: you are being told to interpret this expression as though $0^0$ is defined to be $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Who said to you that $0^0 \neq 1$? How would you otherwise extend by continuity the function $x^x$ from $(0,+ \infty)$ to $[0,+\infty)$?

Comment: I wrongly implied that if $0^0$ is *undefined* then it is not equal to $1$. In your example, limits are utilized to extend the continuity for the given function,precisely when $x\to\infty$. Therefore, it is not that obvious to define $0^0$ as $1$

Comment: @DMH16 It is completely obvious, if you do not like situation when $x$ is irrational then look what happens when you tend to $0$ only through the rational numbers, because then $x^x$ is easier to handle.

Comment: Ok then take into consideration the function $\frac{x}{x}$ as $x\to\infty$ which is equal to $1$. Using your logic we should also define $0/0$ to be $1$

Comment: @DMH16 I am not using that logic, $x^x$ when $x$ tends to $0$ is the most natural candidate to define expression $0^0$.

Comment: You are using limits to define an indeterminate form. Correct? I am applying the same logic for the function $\frac{x}{x}$ as $x\to0$ which is one.

Comment: By the way on my previous comments I intended to write as $x\to0$ and not as $x\to\infty$

Comment: I am just saying that it is the most natural way to assign value $1$ to $0^0$ by observing what happens with the function $x^x$ when x tends to zero. @DMH16 That function is the most natural function among all for this type of problem.